# UIView not showing after hiding once

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiview

I have a `UIView` named `scoreView` on `ViewController`. When I load the `ViewController` I hide the `scoreView` in the `viewDidLoad` method. It works fine.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

[super viewDidLoad];
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;
scoreView.hidden = YES;

}
```

Then after being pushed from another view controller to this `ViewController`, I call a method, where I want to show the scoreView. But the scorView is still being hidden. Where is the mistake I am doing?

```
-(void)levelCompleteViewAppear: (NSString *)score{

NSLog(@"This method is called!");
scoreView.hidden = NO ;
[gameScore setText:score];

}
```

This is how I am pushing to the `ViewController` from anothe view controller.

```
-(void)levelComplete{

UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
ViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc levelCompleteViewAppear:scoreLabel.text];

}
```

Comment: Did you debug? Is `scoreView` nil?

Comment: after pushing the view u want to show score view ? of after coming back from another view u want to unhide

Comment: Set `score` as a @property in `ViewController` and call `levelCompleteViewAppear ` in `viewWillAppear:`

Comment: when you want to show uiview need to reset scoreView.hidden = YES;,because control is not going in viewDidLoad method again

Comment: Try with no animation like [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];

Answer (score 3):

Try This,

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addSubview:scrollview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:scrollview];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are pushing the viewController to navigationController, it will not call `viewDidLoad` directly. If you want to make it visible, write it down in `viewWillAppear` or `vieDidAppear` method.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) viewWillAppear{



scoreView.hidden = YES;

}
```

add this in your code

Answer (score 0):

If first time ViewController class in opeining then ViewDidLoad will call but if you are coming back from some other ViewController then ViewDidLoad wont get call for that you need to show your View in ViewWillAppear Or ViewDidAppear.
Suppose you called Class A then ViewDidLoad will get call then again you moved class B then class B viewDidLoad will get call but if you are coming back again to class A then your viewDidLoad wont get call, it will call ViewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

Hope it may clear you more.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)viewWillApper:(BOOL)animated{

scoreView.hidden = NO ;
}
```